# Sending a list of commands

Tags: serial

I have a list of user created commands that get sent serially with a set wait time in seconds. What is the best way to do this in python and have the ability to hit a button to start,  pause and stop the list? Possible threading? But would that lock out my keypad?

Comment: "Best" has to be evaluated against some criteria which you don't give, e.g. speed, memory consumption, portability, whatever. Which part(s) of this are you unsure how to do? Which parts do you already know how to do?

Comment: Okay, best as in won't lock out the keypad as so to be able to start,  stop and pause.  I know threading in windows you have to do some funky callback stuff. I'm new to python so I dont know how to achieve this. A loop that somehow can be paused, or threading etc.

Comment: Which parts do you have working and which parts do you not know how to do?

Comment: I've got the list of commands, it just takes them from a treeview. The treeview has three columns (line number, cmd, and delay). I also know how to send the cards serially,  but I dont know how to implement the delay wanted, then send the next command. But it also needs to be able to pause and stop whenever a button is pushed. So first line is (1,50, 2). When the start button is pushed, it would send the cmd "50" then wait 2 seconds before going to the next line.

Comment: Please don't use comments for additional information. Instead edit your question and improve it with this information.